# Do both of these functions define the same branch of $\sqrt{z^2 - 1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, branch-cuts

Let $\sqrt{\cdot}$ be the function defined by 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{z} &= r^\frac{1}{2} e^{i \frac{\theta}{2}}, \\ 
r &= |z|, \\ 
\theta &= \arg(z), \\ 
-\pi &< \theta \le \pi
\end{align}

Let $$f(z) = z\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{z}}\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{z}}$$
and let 
$$g(z) = \sqrt{z +1}\sqrt{z - 1}.$$
The functions $f$ and $g$ are both branches of the multivalued function implicitly defined by $w^2 = z^2 - 1$. Indeed $f^2(z) = g^2(z) = z^2 - 1$.
Furthermore $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x > 1$, therefore $f = g$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [-1, 1]$ 
by the [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Is there a more direct way to see this from how $\sqrt{\cdot}$ depends on the argument of a number?
It's tempting to factor $\sqrt{z}$ from both factors of $g$ however for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$, in general $\sqrt{\alpha\beta} \neq \sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\beta}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arguments in this answer will always be defined to be in $(-\pi,\pi]$, as in your definition of $\sqrt{z}$.]

The way you have defined square roots, $\sqrt{\alpha\beta}=\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\beta}$ is valid as long as the arguments of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ add to give something inside the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Now suppose $z$ is not real.  Then the arguments of $z$ and $1/z$ have opposite sign, and hence so do the arguments of $z$ and $1+1/z$ (the sign of the argument is the sign of the imaginary part).  Thus the sum of the arguments of $z$ and $1+1/z$ must be in $(-\pi,\pi]$.  That is, $\sqrt{z+1}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+1/z}$.

Now let us consider $z$ and $1-1/z$.  The arguments of these have the same sign, so we must give a more careful argument.  First, note that the arguments of $z$ and $-1/z$ sum to $\pm\pi$.  Now when you add $1$ to $-1/z$, that will shrink the absolute value of its argument (draw a picture if this isn't obvious).  Thus the absolute value of the sum of the arguments of $z$ and $1-1/z$ is less than $\pi$.  This again means $\sqrt{z-1}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-1/z}$.

Thus if $z$ is not real, $\sqrt{1+z}\sqrt{1-z}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+1/z}\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-1/z}=z\sqrt{1+1/z}\sqrt{1-1/z}$.  We can also easily check that this identity holds for $z>1$ and $z<-1$, so it is valid on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you, I've had many answers that gloss over these technicalities. Is this because it is obvious after enough practice or is there widespread misunderstanding?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this obvious--it took me some effort to see why it works.  Though, if I had to show $f(z)=g(z)$, I would probably just use your argument using the identity theorem.

Comment: Dear @EricWofsey is there a typo in your answer in the sentence "This again means $\sqrt{z-1}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+1/z}$ by any chance? (a minus sign instead of a plus one). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LuigiM: Thanks for catching that; I've fixed it.

Comment: dear @EricWofsey sorry for asking you a clarification. Where does the choice of a branch of the square root come into play in your reasoning? I get that in order to have $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ we need to work in the same "branch" but what would change if you take the other branch of the square root? My guess is that you would have a $\sqrt{z}\sqrt{z}=-z$ but I can't justify it

Comment: @LuigiM: I'm not sure what you mean by "take the other branch of the square root"--the equation $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ has three different square roots in it.  The choice of branch is what makes my first sentence (after the parenthetical remark) true.  To have $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ it suffices to know that $\arg(ab)=\arg(a)+\arg(b)$ for your choice of argument.  If $\arg$ is defined to take values in $(-\pi,\pi]$, then this equation is valid iff $\arg(a)+\arg(b)\in(-\pi,\pi]$, since the equation is always true mod $2\pi$.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, sorry bad choice of words (and got confused with similar questions about the integral of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ around a circle, that I'm trying to understand).

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for the clarification!